# PHP regex to include double backslashes in brackets

Tags: php, regex

So I am trying to do a relatively simple php regex to check wether a string contains one of these characters: .,%$@/0123456789 but I also want to check wether it contains a double backslash (I don't want it to evaluate to true if it only contains one backslash) and I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated :)

Here is what I was using so far:

```
preg_match('/[.,%$@\/0-9]/',$string)
```

I am not sur how to include the '\\\\' for the double backslash.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give some examples of strings that pass and examples of strings that fail? What are the expected outcomes for "123", "\\", "123\\", "123abc", "\\abc", etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking for your character set or a double backslash, right? So:

```
preg_match('/[.,%$@\/0-9]|\\\\/',$string)
```

Where `|` means "or".

Comment: I might add that you can also change the pattern delimiter to something other than `/` if you don't want to have to escape the `/` in the character class.

Comment: The only way that this regex will *fail* is if the string contains exactly *zero* permitted characters. If even a single permitted character is present [or a double backslash] the match is successful.

Comment: @Sammitch I read the question as "strings containing at least one of the characters in the class or at least one instance of "\\" should match", but re-reading it, I'm not sure whether it should require at least one out of the class AND at least one instance of "\\"...OP will need to clarify.

Comment: OP has defined his input requirements poorly at best. :P

Answer (score 0):

If the string *must* be made up of the characters you've given, but also *must* contain a double backslash, but not a single backslash, then as far as I can see you're going to need 3 regular expressions.

```
if (
  (!preg_match('/[^.,%$@\/\\0-9]/', $string)) // fails if the string contains a character that is not allowed
  &&
  ! (
    preg_match('/\\/', $string) // contains at least one backslash
    &&
    !preg_match('/\\{2}/') // succeeds if the string contains a double-backslash
  )
) { /* code */ }
```

If you try to combine all your rules into a single regex, you're gonna have a bad time.

There is also the drawback that once the string contains a double-backslash it can then have extra backslashes anywhere, ie '12\3456\78\90' is valid. If this is possible, but not permissible in the input then you might want to consider a regex that strictly checks the format rather than just testing for valid characters.